# Efficient copying of an ensemble in JAX

Tags: python, jax

I have an ensemble of models and want to assign the same parameters to each of the models. Both the models' parameters as well as the new parameters have the same underlying structure. Currently I use the following approach that uses a for-loop.

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

model1 = [
    [jnp.asarray([1]), jnp.asarray([2, 3])],
    [jnp.asarray([4]), jnp.asarray([5, 6])],
]

model2 = [
    [jnp.asarray([2]), jnp.asarray([3, 4])],
    [jnp.asarray([5]), jnp.asarray([6, 7])],
]

models = [model1, model2]

params = [
    [jnp.asarray([3]), jnp.asarray([4, 5])],
    [jnp.asarray([6]), jnp.asarray([7, 8])],
]

models = [jax.tree_map(jnp.copy, params) for _ in range(len(models))]
```

Is there a more efficient way in JAX to assign the parameters from `params` to each model in `models`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JAX arrays are immutable, there's no need to copy the parameter arrays, and you could achieve the same result like this:

```py
models = len(models) * [params]
```

Comment: Wow, that is a very pythonic solution. But why is there no need of copying JAX arrays if they are immutable?

Comment: The only benefit of copying would be that if you modify the original in-place, the copy cannot be modified. But if it's impossible to modify in-place, then that removes all reason to perform a copy.